# On Linux I want to stop authentication for a specific Windows server that will use it to send mail using Sendmail

Tags: php, linux, sendmail, windows-server-2016

I have a Windows 2016 server that needs to access sendmail from our Linux server. When I update the php.ini folder to use the Linux server's email server I get the below error:

```
PHP Warning:  mail(): SMTP server response: 530 5.7.0 Authentication required
```

The php.ini file looks like the below:

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = admin.site.com
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 587
auth_username = name
auth_password = password
```

Instead of authenticating I rather just disable it for this particular server. Any help on this would be GREATLY appreciated

Comment: Name SMTP/MTA server running on Linux/Unix.  Standard approach would be to allow relaying based on connecting IP address.

Comment: @AnFi how would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You may use `access` table to make sendmail allow relaying based on sending host IP address.

```
connect:192.168.0.5         RELAY
```

https://www.sendmail.org/~ca/email/doc8.12/cf/m4/anti_spam.html#access_db